# Can someone please help me understand how a regression model with more variables might be sig when a simpler model is not

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, mixed-model, dimensionality-reduction

Basically, I reduced a mixed effects linear model from 16 total factors/interactions down to 7 with most remaining factors being 'significant' (~ .05) or highly relevant to the design (and still close to .10). It looks good and it is theoretically sensible. BUT if I test at least a few of those factors by themselves, their p is closer to .3 or above.

This is apparent in the post-estimation plots for each model as well (obviously), but I am just keen to understand why the complex model results in one outcome, and why I can or cannot trust that versus the simple model with only the single factor.

Many thanks.

Comment: _Can someone please ELI5 why..._  There are some issues with the title. Please check and fix the typos.

Answer (score 3):

You're conducting two fundamentally different tests. When you fit the full model, in the table of parameter estimates and SEs, each p-value listed corresponds to the test of whether the coefficient of the corresponding predictor is 0 *after having adjusted for all the other predictors in the model*. In contrast, when you fit a model with just one predictor, you are *not* adjusting for the effects of the other predictors.

As an aside, I'm concerned about how you "reduced" your model. If you did so by attempting to remove insignificant effects, you technically shouldn't then report p-values associated with the final model. (By doing so, you are effectively assuming that the coefficients of all the predictors you removed are *exactly* 0 -- which is almost certainly incorrect -- and potentially rendering inference based on your final model invalid.)  Why not just leave all the predictors in the model and then conduct inference?

Comment: Thanks for the response. That does make sense. Regarding model reduction, I was taught (and recently read) that one reduction method was to run the model, pull out non-significant effects (typically starting with higher order interactions), and then re-reunning the model with the reduced terms. Then repeating this process until there was a smaller subset only including significant, or near significant terms.

Comment: @pazmuffin That’s called stepwise regression. Yes, people do it, yet there are considerable problems. [This](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/stepwise-regression-problems/) explanation of why comes from a Stata webpage, but the statistics theory does not rely on any particular software (it is correct whether you use Stata or SAS or SPSS or Python or R or Julia or…). The gist is that you’re calculating the p-value as if you hadn’t done the variable screening, and this ruins the inferences downstream of that screening step.

Comment: Thanks Dave. So it's preferable then to just run the complete model, and leave in all factors despite them having very small coefficients and high p-values? The model itself is inherently subjective (I am picking and choosing the factors based on some degree of pertinence) so at what point am I cherry picking effects anyways? Meaningful inference is all I really care about, and fyi these data are exploratory behaviour data.

Comment: Should also point out that it's a relatively small sample (n~35, each with 4 scores), but the best we could do given our constraints/costs.